# How can i enqueue reactjs file to wordpress theme file to make it visible in local server

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I have buiilt a wodpress theme using reactjs. And I used graphql for wordpress api to get data. But the problem is I am unable to enqueue  reactjs file with wordpress  theme files.

To do the same i found something like this on google but its not working

```
<?php

/**
 * Gets the contents of the Create React App manifest file
 *
 * @return array|bool|string
 */
function get_app_manifest() {
    $manifest = file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/app/build/asset-manifest.json' );
    $manifest = (array) json_decode( $manifest );

    return $manifest;
}

/**
 * Gets the path to the stylesheet compiled by Create React App
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_app_stylesheet() {
    $manifest = get_app_manifest();

    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/app/build/' . $manifest['main.css'];
}

/**
 * Gets the path to the built javascript file compiled by Create React App
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_app_script() {
    $manifest = get_app_manifest();

    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/app/build/' . $manifest['main.js'];
}

/**
 * Enqueues the scripts
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    enqueue_react_app();
} );

/**
 * Enqueues the stylesheet and js
 */
function enqueue_react_app() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'graphql-workshop', get_app_script(), array(), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'graphql-workshop', get_app_stylesheet(), array(), false, false );
}
```

Is it correct or is there some other way or is this missing something.
I really need to know this.

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers a function that can gives you files list and directories. By using glob you can list every .js file in your directory, and then enqueue them by a loop.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts(){
   foreach( glob( get_template_directory(). '/path/*.js' ) as $file ) 
   {
        // $file contains the name and extension of the file
        wp_enqueue_script( $file,get_template_directory_uri().'/path/'.$file);
   }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');
```

A side not is that glob uses relative path, but wp_enqueue_script uses URLs. That is why I used different functions to get the folder's path and URI.

Comment: which file should i target from react package as create-react-app contains a huge no.of files